# how can I import a dependent file into the main file in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

consider I have a mainfile.py and some other files like a.py, b.py, c.y etc, which match exactly in a specific line of the main file, how is it possible for me to import one or all of them into the main file even in the middle of a loop?. I am familiar with the;

```
import sys

sys.path.append('path/to/...')
```

but it doesn't help since the little files are completely dependent to the main file. It is just like I have cut a part of the main file to other files and I want the main file to replace them just like they are a part of the main file.

Comment: Maybe you should read a little bit more about [modules and packages](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html).

Comment: Assuming a.py, b.py, and c.y only contain definitions, just import all of them at the beginning of mainfile.py.

Comment: the problem is they are not just definitions, they consist of a process over some variables which are defined in the mainfile.

Comment: In this case you would create a [function](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/functions.html) and import at the beginning, too. In case you tried, there is no `#include` in Python.